# Content DB size of a restored webapplication is huge

Tags: content-database

I have restored a Sitecollection(Export-SPsite) which was migrated from SP2010 to SP2013. This new site's (without any content) actual size is 900MB (Got it from SharePoint designer), However the Content DB size is around 90GB. I checked the Diskusage from SSMS and it shows Docstreams table with over 10Lrecords has around 84 GB space occupied with very old data.

Please can someone suggest me a way to remove old records or reduce content DB size to some extent. Because I think,new sitecollection with 100GB Disk space is not a practical.

Is there a way to take backup of a sitecollection without the docstream table(shredded storage).

Answer (score 1):

- Create a new ContentDatabase `New-SPContentDatabase -Name YourNewDatabase -WebApplication http://yourwebapp.com`
- Move all existing SiteCollections from the huge database to the new one `Get-SPSite -Limit all -ContentDatabase HugeDatabaseName | Move-SPSite -DestinationDatabase YourNewDatabase`. Please note that the SiteCollections will be unaccessiable during the move!
- Perform an `iisreset /noforce` as Move-SPSite tells you
- Delete the huge database from SharePoint and SQL-Server with `Remove-SPContentDatabase HugeDatabaseName`

Comment: I did that, unfortunately the size is same. Move-SPsite moved my entire sitecollection to new contentDatabase including Docstreams table. :(

Answer (score 0):

In your situation there are a couple of things you need to check.

- From Central Admininistration > Manage Content Databases > Select the web app and see how many site collections in that content db.
- Also from Central Admininistration check the size of the site collection(s)
- Make sure there is nothing in the recycle bin( both level recycle bin)

If it is an OOTB new site collection (as you mentioned) then you can take the backup of the site collection using `Backup-SPSite` and then create a new content DB & restore the site collection in it.

Comment: Removed everything from Recyclebin, The issue here is Docstreams table  has pretty old data (around 120K records) with over 84 GB. Is there any way to remove the old records from the table. One more point worth mentioning this sitecollection was migrated from SP2010.